# Tangent plane of $z = e^{x\cdot y}\cdot \sin\left ( x^{2} + y^{2} \right )$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Assuming $$z = e^{x\cdot y}\cdot \sin\left ( x^{2} + y^{2} \right )$$
How can I find tangent plane equation @ $\displaystyle \left ( \frac{\pi }{2} , \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right )$ ?

Comment: @vkeles You're missing a third coordinate in $\displaystyle \left(\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right)$, do you perhaps mean $\displaystyle \left(\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}, z\left(\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right)\right)$?

Comment: There isnt a third coordinate in the question.

Comment: The plane can be written as a function of $(x,y)$.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes. But there's something wrong with the question. We're talking about a graph of a two variable function. The graph lies in $\Bbb R^3$. We can't simply consider a $\Bbb R^2$ element in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: @GitGud: I think you had it right above, consider the surface $\phi(x,y,z) = e^{xy} \sin(x^2+y^2)-z = 0$. Find the gradient of $\phi$.

Comment: In later courses, one may work from the parameter space (x,y) to talk about the surface in $R^3$. So the tangent space in $R^3$ may be associated with a point in the "chart", or plane, or parameter space.

Comment: But you can also think about it in $R^3$, of course. For instance, if $r_0$ is the point that Git Gud mentions above, then our plane is the set of $r$ satisfying $\nabla\phi(r_0)\cdot(r-r_0)=0$. I think we're starting to tie all the above comments together. And I think it's okay to say that the equation for the plane (they all simplify to the same equation), is based at $(x_0,y_0)$ or $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$. In some sense, they are the same point (the chart map will be a diffeomorphism).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You have $(x_0,y_0)=(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$
$$ f_x(x_0,y_0)(x−x_0)+f_y(x_0,y_0)(y−y_0)−(z−z_0)=0 .$$

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the formula?

It's not hard to remember, it roughly has the form $dz={\partial z\over\partial x}dx+{\partial z\over\partial y}dy$.

That is, I think you would simply use:

$$z=z(a,b)+{\partial z\over\partial x}(a,b)\cdot(x-a)+{\partial z\over\partial y}(a,b)\cdot(y-b).$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

Let $\phi(x,y,z) = e^{xy} \sin(x^2+y^2)-z$. Then a point is on the surface iff $\phi(x,y,z) = 0$. The tangent plane at $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is given by  $\langle \nabla \phi(x_0,y_0,z_0), (x,y,z)- (x_0,y_0,z_0) \rangle = 0$.

Let $\theta = \frac{{\pi }^{2}+2}{4}$, then the plane is given by:
$$\langle \begin{bmatrix}
{e}^{\frac{\pi }{2\sqrt{2}}} ( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sin \theta +\pi \,\cos \theta ) \\
{e}^{\frac{\pi }{2\sqrt{2}}} ( \frac{\pi}{2} \,\sin \theta  +\sqrt{2}\,\cos \theta ) \\
-1
\end{bmatrix},  
\begin{bmatrix}
x-\frac{\pi}{2} \\
y-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
z-{e}^{\frac{\pi }{2 \sqrt{2}}}\,\sin \theta
\end{bmatrix}
 \rangle = 0$$